# Update Vue template on resize event

Tags: vuejs2

I have a component in which I create an array that contains other arrays:

```
mounted() {
  this.populateTrackedMoviesState();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.MoviesInRows);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.MoviesInRows);
  };
}

MoviesInRows() {
  const numberOfMovies = Math.floor((window.innerWidth - 24) / 185);
  console.log(chunk(TrackedMoviestStore.state.trackedMovieList, numberOfMovies).length);
  return chunk(TrackedMoviestStore.state.trackedMovieList, numberOfMovies);
}
```

The important thing happening here is that when I resize the `console.log` in the `MoviesInRows` shows the correct value.

In my template I render a list of movies based on the `MoviesInRows()` method:

```
<ul id="movieList" v-for='(movieRow, index) in MoviesInRows()' :key='index'>
  <li
    v-for='movie in movieRow'
    :key='movie.id'>
      <MovieInOverview :movie=movie />
      {{ MoviesInRows().length }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `{{ MoviesInRows().length }}` never changes, although the `console.log` in the `MoviesInRows` shows that return value should change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how this resolved the issue but:

```
numberOfMovies = 0;

MoviesInRows() {
  this.numberOfMovies = Math.floor((window.innerWidth - 24) / 185);
  return chunk(TrackedMoviestStore.state.trackedMovieList, this.numberOfMovies);
}
```

Now when I resize the screen the template gets updated correctly.